# How exclude a particular id from SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have table which comprises of categories listed, among them are parent categories and they have there respective child categories.
I want to display

1. Parent categories ( only if they don't have child categories)
2. All child categories.

**Example:** `Laptop` category doesn't have any child and hence **it should be** displayed. But `Books` category has child like `Electronic books`, `Mechanical Books` etc. in such circumstance only child categories like `Electronic books`, `Mechanical Books` should be displayed and Books **should not be** displayed.

[image]

So what could be the Mysqli query in order to achieve the same? Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try to do? ..

Comment: Something like `WHERE category_id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM ...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you're querying categories that don't have any children. This can be done with the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT category_title
FROM   categories c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   categories p
                   WHERE  p.category_id = c.parent_id)
```